# Determine the number of positive integers such that $[\frac{a}{2}] + [\frac{a}{3}] + [\frac{a}{5}] = a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:**

Determine the number of positive integers such that:

$$\Big[\frac{a}{2}\Big] + \Big[\frac{a}{3}\Big] + \Big[\frac{a}{5}\Big] = a$$

(where [x] is the greatest integer function)

**Attempted solution:**

The greatest integer function is essentially the floor function. The largest integer that is less than x.

In order for three numbers to sum up to an integer, they can:

- all be integers
- one of them are integers and the remaining two add up to become an integer

If a is even, then

$$\Big[\frac{a}{2}\Big]$$

is also even and we could remove the floor function, since the result is an even integer. This is not possible of a is odd. Similar method can be used for the others, assuming they are divisible by 3 and divisible by 5.

I am not entirely sure how to continue. I thought about replacing a with $2n$ or $2n+1$ in the two different scenarios, but I am not sure that will work since it looks like it just reduces to $a = 0$.

There does not seem to be a general solution methodology for floor functions in the same way that there are for the absolute value function?

The number of positive integers turns out to be 30 according to Wolfram Alpha, which is suspiciously identical to $5*3*2 = 30$ This would perhaps indicate that one should put the left-hand side together on the same fraction, but I am not entirely clear how this is done with floor functions.

Comment: "if $a$ is even then $\lfloor \frac a2 \rfloor$ is also even."  Why?  What if, say, $a=2$?

Comment: I think you are somewhat confused here. You say 'in order for three numbers to sum to an integer, they can either all be integers or one of them is an integer and the other two add to become an integer', but (a) that's not even true (consider $\frac12+\frac13+\frac16$), and (b) it's irrelevant here, because _all_ the quantities involved in your equation are integers.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I never stated those where the *only* ways to produce an integer, only that those two scenarios produced an integer. It was part of an attempt to understand if and when you can remove floor functions (i.e. when the fractions would be integers already before the floor function being applied).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \frac{a}{2} + \frac{a}{3} + \frac{a}{5}-3<\Big[\frac{a}{2}\Big] + \Big[\frac{a}{3}\Big] + \Big[\frac{a}{5}\Big]=a\leq \frac{a}{2} + \frac{a}{3} + \frac{a}{5}$$

Comment: I got 29 roots.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire You can write your roots and I'll find your mistakes.

Comment: For what it's worth, I checked all integers $1\le a \le 10^7$ in Mathematica and found 29 solutions.

Comment: @John Barber I am ready to post these roots.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?

Comment: 6, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 31, 32, 33, 
34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 44, 47, 49, 53, 59. Note that these are all under 90, as predicted by the above inequality.

Comment: @John Barber Exactly!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg did you actually use hit-and-trial or is there some pattern I'm failing to see?

Comment: No, I went with a hard way

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use $$x-1<[x]\leq x$$ then you get $$ \frac{a}{2} + \frac{a}{3} + \frac{a}{5}-3\leq a\leq \frac{a}{2} + \frac{a}{3} + \frac{a}{5}$$
I get 29 solutions...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $a=30k+r$ where $k\in \Bbb N\cup\{0\}$ and $0\le r<30$. Therefore$$31k+\Big[\frac{r}{2}\Big] + \Big[\frac{r}{3}\Big] + \Big[\frac{r}{5}\Big] = 30k+r$$or$$k+\Big[\frac{r}{2}\Big] + \Big[\frac{r}{3}\Big] + \Big[\frac{r}{5}\Big] = r$$

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,I just made a mistake.
I think the answer is 30.
when a=2k,$k\in N$;
Compared to$a\over2$+$a\over3$+$a\over5$,the left side may less $i\over3$+$j\over5$(i=0,1,2;j=0,1,2,3,4),
so there are 1x3x5-1=14 numbers fitting it.(Because what the left side less will equal to($a\over2$+$a\over3$+$a\over5$-$a$) ,and i,j cannot equals to 0 at the same time as $a\neq0$)

when a=2k+1,$k\in N$;
Compared to$a\over2$+$a\over3$+$a\over5$,the left side may less $1\over2$+$i\over3$+$j\over5$(i=0,1,2;j=0,1,2,3,4),so there are 1x3x5=15 numbers fitting it.
Above all,14+15=29 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  = x - \left\{ x \right\}\quad \left| {\,0 \le \left\{ x \right\} < 1} \right.
$$
then the equation becomes
$$
\eqalign{
  & 0 = \left\lfloor {{a \over 2}} \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {{a \over 3}} \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {{a \over 5}} \right\rfloor  - a =   \cr 
  &  = {a \over 2} + {a \over 3} + {a \over 5} - a - \left\{ {{a \over 2}} \right\} - \left\{ {{a \over 3}} \right\} - \left\{ {{a \over 5}} \right\} =   \cr 
  &  = {a \over {30}} - \left\{ {{a \over 2}} \right\} - \left\{ {{a \over 3}} \right\} - \left\{ {{a \over 5}} \right\} \cr} 
$$

Actually, for integral $a$,  we have
$$
\left\{ {{a \over 2}} \right\} \le {1 \over 2},\quad \left\{ {{a \over 3}} \right\} \le {2 \over 3},\quad \left\{ {{a \over 5}} \right\} \le {4 \over 5}
$$

so a first result we get
$$
{a \over {30}} = \left\{ {{a \over 2}} \right\} + \left\{ {{a \over 3}} \right\} + \left\{ {{a \over 5}} \right\}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 0 \le a < 90
$$

Consider values of $a$ which are multiples of the three factors
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{2b} \over {30}} = \left\{ {{{2b} \over 3}} \right\} + \left\{ {{{2b} \over 5}} \right\} \le \left\{ {{2 \over 3}} \right\} + \left\{ {{4 \over 5}} \right\}
 = {{22} \over {15}}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 0 \le a_{\,mult2}  \le 44  \cr 
  & {{3c} \over {30}} = \left\{ {{{3c} \over 2}} \right\} + \left\{ {{{3c} \over 5}} \right\} \le \left\{ {{1 \over 2}} \right\} + \left\{ {{3 \over 5}} \right\}
 = {{11} \over {10}}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 0 \le a_{\,mult3}  \le 33  \cr 
  & {{5d} \over {30}} = \left\{ {{{5d} \over 2}} \right\} + \left\{ {{{5d} \over 3}} \right\} \le \left\{ {{1 \over 2}} \right\} + \left\{ {{2 \over 3}} \right\}
 = {5 \over 6}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 0 \le a_{\,mult5}  \le 25 \cr} 
$$
which means that you can do some sieving in testing the values of $a$ from $0$ to $59$.